# When I open a php file in the browser it gets a 404 error

Tags: php

When I open a php file on the browser, a 404 error appears. When I search in the browser localhost:1234/index.php, a 404 error message appears. How is the browser set up to open php files?

Comment: Do you have some local server installed on your computer?

Comment: 404 error means that it have not found the file. Review your localhost webserver settings and check in which folder is pointing it and if your index.php file is there.